# Effect of position on special characters, bash

Tags: bash

I'm going to use `!` as an example of a special character, but this also happens for `$`.

Why does the `!` operator lose its special meaning when it's at the end of the argument passed to, say, `echo`, but not when it's inside the argument? I guess this has something to do with concatenation, but I can't find any reference material. Can someone explain what's happening here?

```
$echo "hi"!
$hi!
$echo "hi"!"bye"
-bash: !: event not found
```

Comment: If you're referring to when `$` or `!` appear with nothing following, then I think it's because they _require_ something to follow it in order to be 'special' – `*` is another special character, but it doesn't behave like this.

Comment: echo "hi"$ ->
hi$

echo "hi"$"bye" ->
hibye

Comment: And isn't * only special if it's preceded by $,. i.e. used in parameter expansion? https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: Sorry with `*` I was referring to ["pathname expansion" ... "special pattern characters"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html). ie. this character is not normally treated literally by the shell (because it's special).

Comment: Your `echo hi$"bye"` example is covered in the manual under [Quoting: Locale-Translation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Locale-Translation.html)